# Django urls recognition error

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the project `myproject` and an app `myapp` listed below. When I try url `/add` I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/add/
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
The current URL, add/, didn't match any of these.
```

#### settings configuration:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
```

#### myproject/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

#### myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'main'),
    url(r'^add/', 'foo'),
)
```

#### myapp/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def main(request):
    return render(request, "main.html", {'test': 1})

def foo(request):
    return render(request, "add.html")
```

#### templates/main.html

```
{{ test }}
```

#### templates/add.html

```
{{ test }}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')),
```

means that only *completely empty* URLs will be passed to the myapp include. You mean this:

```
url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
```

Comment: Or, `r'^add/` and then adjust `myapp/urls.py` accordingly.